# Allowing backspaces and numbers and slashes on key press

Tags: javascript

I have this keypress function that only allow numbers and "/" i want to add to it the backspace.
Does anyone have an idea?

```
function OnKeyPressNumberText(sender, eventArgs)
{         
    var char = eventArgs.get_keyCharacter();
    //will allow just letters and "-" 
    var exp = /[^0-9/]/g;
    if (exp.test(char)) {
        eventArgs.set_cancel(true);
    }            
}
```

Comment: It's not c# nor asp.net it's javascript ...

Comment: Keymaster is pretty decent BTW, handles a lot of the keyboard event edge-cases/hackarounds/uglyness. https://github.com/madrobby/keymaster

Answer (score 2):

Some command keys have char values as well:

Enter - 13

BackSpace - 8

Escape - 27

...

Just skip all chars that are less than 32 (or less than space)

```
  var char = eventArgs.get_keyCharacter();

  // let command keys (BackSpace, Enter, Tab/Shift+Tab, Escape...) do its work
  if (char < ' ') {
    eventArgs.set_cancel(true); // <- see Mike Mouannes comments below

    return;
  }

  //will allow just letters and "-" 
  var exp = /[^0-9/]/g;

  if (exp.test(char)) {
    eventArgs.set_cancel(true);
  }
```

Comment: by doing eventArgs.set_cancel(true); we are allowing numbers and not restraining them. And the key char=8 didn't work on firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Only `keydown`, `keyup` events can handle control keys.
See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/PhZtZ/1/) fiddle.
Try to press `backspace` in the field and button `a` for example and you can see that when you press `backspace` only `keydown` and `keyup` events are launches and when you press `a` key launces all thee events.

And see when you press `a` key `event.keyCode` different in `keydown`, `keyup` (65) and `keypress` (97) events.